# Android, an XML for EVERY image button?

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I wish to change the image of a button when it is pressed. I am doing so in a selector XML file which is fine, and seems the same in all of the examples I have seen so far.

Am I correct though in saying that a separate XML file is required for EVERY button? I have one activity with 6 buttons, so does that mean in order to represent each of those buttons being pressed, I need 6 XML files?

That seems very cumbersome so maybe someone can shed some light on the best way to do it.
Here are the images I want to use for `pressed`:
[image: screen shot]

Not `pressed`:
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the buttons to look the same, you'll only need one XML file to define the appearance of the button. You can use that same appearance for as many imagebuttons as you like. 
If you want the same background, but different icons you still only need one selector file, but the images you feed it should just be the red and blue squares, with no question mark. Then, as the src for the imagebutton, you would put the transparent image of just the question mark, just the clock, just the euro, etc

Comment: Well the images I posted show what I wanted, basically some symbol/picture, with a background colour gradient that changes while the symbol/picture stays the same, I figured this was only achievable in Photoshop with different images?

Comment: I mean, since every button will have the same pressed and un-pressed state, you only need the one selector XML file to define that pressed and un-pressed. Then on each of your imagebuttons you put an  android:background="selector-file-name.xml"

Comment: Hmm, the selector points to 1 image for pressed and un-pressed, but I have 6 buttons, one will have that ? symbol located above, one will have a clock/history symbol, one will have a € symbol etc... so can I make 1 selector choose the correct image out of 6 pressed/un-pressed based on the button that is using it? Sorry if I'm not clear :)

Comment: Oh, I see, you want all the buttons to have the same red/blue states, but with different images on top, not necessarily the question mark. In that case, you still only need one selector file, but the images you feed it should just be the red and blue squares, with no question mark. Then, as the src for the imagebutton, you would put the transparent image of just the question mark, just the clock, just the euro, etc.

Comment: Yeah I just came to that conclusion myself thanks! I did not realise you could use the background _and_ src (as a foreground) for an imagebutton. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer with the new info, for future reference. Good luck with the rest of your app!

Answer (score 1):

No. You just need to define your State Selector list once, and can reuse it for as many Views as you like (assuming you want them all to look the same).